# Allow a few routes and block all other ASP.NETMVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service

I have an application in ASP.NET MVC that we bought that has multiples possible routes and that might get even bigger because we can dynamically add pluggins. We're talking hundreds of different pages and controllers. We modified/added the ones that we needed (mostly reskinning). And now we have to make sure that only the pages that we modified are accessible to the user. Someone that knows the application that we bought could go to routes that we don't want him to see.

So in the end, my question is :

Is there a way to deny access to all the routes except the ones that I want.

Since the application is HUGE. I can't/don't want to go to individual controller and add a redirect or a Data annotation. Also, I dont want to list every url I deny because that would also be crazy long and would not work if we add a plugin later on. I have like 300 url to deny, 20 to allow..
I'm thinking something like this in the webconfig ??

```
deny *
permit mycontroller/action1
permit mycontroller/action2
```

I should also add, that this application does not use any kind of authentication/authorization. I want any user to be able to use the application.

We're hosting it in Azure wep app, would that be a solution ?

Comment: So you want to just maintain a white list that will contain only allowed URLs, right ?

Comment: Yes, that's kinda it

Comment: @CodeNotFound I added an answer if you're curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is stuck with the same problem, here's how I it.

It's all done in the web.config of the application:

You start by denying everything with this

```
 <authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
<authentication mode="None" />
```

Then, you can whitelist the URLs that you want like this:

```
  <location path="mycontroller/action1">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

```
<location path="mycontroller/action2">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

So every URL dans does not have a location tag is considered not valid and will raise a 401 exception. You can then do what you want from there.

Hope this helps someone :)

Comment: Great solution without coding :) But I think it is too verbose.

Answer (score -1):

use the `[Authorize]` attribute at the controller level and then `[AllowAnonymous]` for the action

```
[Authorize]
Public class mycontroller : Controller
{
  Public ActionResult action1 ()
  {
    Return View();
  }

  [AllowAnonymous]
  Public ActionResult action2 ()
  {
    Return View ();
  }
}
```

Comment: As I said in the question, I can't do that. There's too many controllers and there will be some added dynamically...

Comment: then you have some bigger issues.  You probably shouldn't be dynamically creating controllers.  I cannot think of a good reason to do that.  Post your code above.

Comment: Have you read the question ? It says that some controllers can be added to the solution via new plugins. Or if the company that codes the plugins changes it's controllers or add one, I dont wanna have to go into the production application and modify the code... I can't post the code.. there's like 10M lines of code, and I don't think that's relevant.

Comment: I still don't think it would be wise to do so.  If that's the case then you should use a base class controller for subsets of controllers with separate permission sets and define at that level.